# How to display related tags in django tagging?

Tags: django, tagging, django-tagging

i am using django tagging. can anyone give any example as to how can i show the related tags, when the object related to a particular tag is displayed? Something like similar tags in stackoverflow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [get_related](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/tagging/models.py#393) manager which will:

> Retrieve a list of instances of the specified model which share
>   tags with the model instance obj ordered by the number of
>   shared tags in descending order.

To use this you could create a template tag such as:

```
   @register.inclusion_tag(your_template)
   def related_objects(object, limit=3):
       objects = TaggedItem.objects.get_related(object,object.__class__)
       return {'objects': objects[:limit]}
```

**Edit for comment**

to get a list of similar tags you can use related_for_model, which will return *"other tags used by items which have all the given tags"*

Comment: thank you, but i am want to display the related tags not the items from my models that share tags. Is there anyway to do this? to give you example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/django/info), something like the side bar showing related tags.